# string to lua function?

Tags: lua, closures

I have a string, something like:

```
local func = "1 == 3"
```

How can I convert this into a function to execute and get a result from within another function? Like:

```
function CheckFunc(func)
 local ret = functon() return func end

 return ret
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`loadstring()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadstring) is the function You're looking for :)

In your case it would be used like:
`local func = loadstring("return (1==3)")`

Answer (score 6):

```
local func = "1 == 3"

function wrap(s)
    return loadstring("(function() return "..s.." end)()")
end

funcWrapped = wrap(func)

if funcWrapped() then
    print "One eqauls Three"
else
    print "One doesn't equal Three"
end
```

Would output

```
One doesn't equal Three
```

NOTE: You should use @Kamiccolo's `loadstring` in place of mine within `wrap`

Answer (score 4):

In Lua 5.1, you can use [`loadstring`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadstring%29), as the other answers have already said:

```
local func = loadstring("return(1==3)")
```

In Lua 5.2, it's better to use [`load`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-load)

```
local func = load("return(1==3)")
```